# C# member cannot be accessed with an instance reference

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, private, member

So i have these variables

```
List<string> files, images = new List<string>();
string rootStr;
```

And this threaded function

```
private static int[] thread_search(string root,List<string> files, List<string> images)
```

But when I try to start the thread:

```
trd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.thread_search(rootStr,files,images)));
```

I get this error:

> Error 1   Member 'UnusedImageRemover.Form1.thread_search(string,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List)' cannot be accessed with an
>   instance reference; qualify it with a type name
>   instead   E:\Other\Projects\UnusedImageRemover\UnusedImageRemover\Form1.cs    149 46  UnusedImageRemover

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a static method, meaning it does not belong to an instance. `this` refers to the current instance, but since it's static, that doesn't make sense.

Just remove the `this.`, and you should be good.

**EDIT**

Removing `this.` gets you a different exception. You are supposed to pass in a `void` delegate into the `ThreadStart` constructor, and you are invoking the method too early, and passing in the result (`int[]`). You can pass in a lambda instead, like:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    List<string> files = new List<string>(), images = new List<string>();
    string rootStr = "";

    var trd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => thread_search(rootStr, files, images)));
    trd.Start();
}

private static int[] thread_search(string root, List<string> files, List<string> images {
    return new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

Now the thread has a delegate to your search function, with a closure on the parameters - you'll want to read up on threads and closures if you're not familiar with them already.

Comment: `trd = new Thread(newThreadStart( thread_search( rootStr, files, images)));`
This causes the following error:
Method name expected 
@Joe Enos

Comment: Now you'll have a different problem because you're invoking the method too soon. I'll add an edit with some help there.